Is it possible to arrange two summations in this way?
Can I always arrange those summations in this way $$\sum_x^N f(x) \sum_y^N g(x , y) = \sum_y^N \sum_x^N f(x) \cdot g(x,y) $$ for some positive integer $N< +\infty$.
EDIT: $f$ and $g$ are two discrete functions that dipends on positive integers $x$ and $y$.

What is $f$ and $g$?

Sorry, edited .

Can you make the bounds of summation more clear? Are we summing from $0$ to $\infty$?

It's possible if $\sum_y\sum_x\left\lvert f(x)g(x,y)\right\rvert<\infty$ or $f(x)$ and $g(x,y)$ are always non-negative.
